# Mirth: dynamically determine which SOAP method to call

Tags: hl7, mirth

Consider a Mirth channel with a Destination of a SOAP Sender. The WSDL is successfully loaded and has more than one method available. Each method would take a different number of arguments. Example methods:

- `AddPerson()`
- `UpdatePerson()`
- `DeletePerson()`
- `MergePerson()`
- `UnmergePerson()`

Given the set of HL7 message event types,  i.e.

- A28 = Add Person
- A31 = Update Person
- A29 = Delete Person
- etc

**Question**: How would you setup a Destination in Mirth to have the variable's value determine which SOAP Method is called?

It doesn't necessarily have to be a SOAP Sender. Could be any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure you can dynamically select the method on the fly, but you could setup a destination per MessageType and use filters to ensure that a message is routed to the correct destination (method).

I will look into the dynamic select. Perhaps the method is available via a javascript transformer object.